Trigonometric integral with exponential
Is there a tricky way to compute
$$
I = \int_{-\pi}^{0} \exp(\cos(\phi)) \sin^2(\phi) d\phi \qquad ?
$$
If I let $$u = \cos(\phi),$$ I get:
$$I = - \int_{-1}^{1} \exp(u) \sqrt{1-u^2} du  \quad ... $$
but I still don't see how I could manage with that...
Thanks in advance for your ideas !

Wolfram Alpha could not find an indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions but numerically it evaluated it to 2.03971.

Your edit revises the integral's value to $\pi I_1(1)$, in terms of Bessel functions.

Please, do not change the problem after posting.

This integral can be written in the following ways:
$$
I=\begin{cases}
\int_0^\pi \exp(\cos \phi)\frac{1-\cos 2\phi}{2}d\phi&,\quad \text{substituting $\cos 2\phi=1-2\sin^2\phi$}\\
\int_0^\pi \exp(\cos \phi)\cos\phi d\phi&,\quad \text{integration by parts (IBP)}\\
\frac{d}{du}\int_0^\pi \exp(u\cos \phi) d\phi|_{u=1}&,\quad \text{IBP and Feynman's trick}\\
\int_0^\pi \exp(\cos \phi) d\phi-\frac{d^2}{du^2}\int_0^\pi \exp(u\cos \phi) d\phi|_{u=1}&,\quad \text{Splitting and Feynman's trick}
\end{cases}
$$
and as such, by using the definition of the modified Bessel functions of first kind we arrive at the following solutions:
$$
I=\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}I_0(1)-\frac{\pi}{2}I_2(1)\\
\pi I_1(1)\\
\pi I_0'(1)\\
\pi I_0(1)-\pi I_0''(1)
\end{cases},
$$
where $I_n(x)$ is the modified Bessel functions of first kind and order $n$.
